# What should I do about being issued the wrong fiji visa?

Tags: visas, fiji

I'm currently traveling in Fiji on a combined conference/vacation trip.  They issued me a 14 day business visa when I entered Fiji, but this isn't long enough to cover my conference + vacation.  It's only one day short, so I didn't realize the problem until I left the airport.  What should I do in this situation?

Comment: I don't make this an answer because I don't know specifically about Fiji. But in many countries, including the USA, the visa only needs to be good on your day of arrival. How long you are allowed to stay is a separate independent decision. In the USA, the stamp in your passport when you arrived will tell you how long you can actually stay. It is quite common that students, for instance, only get a three-month visa but are allowed to stay for several years until they graduate.

Answer (score 5):

**You can apply to extend your visa**.  [High Commission of Fiji, Australia](http://www.fijihighcom.com/our-mission-othermenu-63/20-do-i-need-a-visa.html):

> It is possible to apply for an additional two weeks beyond the
>   fourteen (14) day period (maximum of six (6) weeks from the date of
>   arrival) at a fee of $F185. Application for the extension must be made
>   within the first 14 days NOT after. The following documents must be
>   submitted with your application for extension:
>
> - Letter from the employer
> - Completed Application of Permit Extension Form
> - Confirmed booking
> - Fee $185
>
> Applications for extension on the relevant form (see above) are to be
>   sent to the Immigration Department:
>
> Director of Immigration, Department of Immigration, PO BOX 2224, Government Buildings, Suva, Fiji Islands
>   (679) 3312 622

Comment: It seems very odd to need a letter from my employer for the vacation part of my trip.  In fact, business is only 5 days of the trip.  It seems like there should be an alternative solution.  Is there not a way to exchange my business visa for a tourist visa?

Comment: You have a business visa, so them's the rules.  I'm not familiar with Fiji specifically, but rarely if ever is it possible to "exchange" a visa without leaving the country.